# bat file: command dos to exit dos after executing it

Tags: batch-file, dos

i want to edit a bat file where i set a certain systems variables, in order to  close the dos after the modification is done.

Comment: Are you actually trying to shut down a machine running MS-DOS, or are you trying to close a command prompt on a modern version of Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, which has a few ideas in it...

```
TITLE My batch file
:: content here
GOTO :END
:END
FOR /l %%a in (30,-1,1) do (TITLE %TITLE% -- Closing in %%as&ping -n 2 -w 1 127.0.0.1>NUL)
:: then, explicit exit (not required)
exit /B 1 >nul
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the command

```
exit
```

This should close the dos/command window.